# how to save user state in bot v4 so that it remain persistent during whole conversation

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-cosmosdb, chatbot

I am using below code to save user state.It is getting saved in cosmos but while I am trying to retrieve it in next turn it is giving null.Is there any way to make it persistent for whole conversation.

```
 private IStatePropertyAccessor<ChatState> _maindialogState; 
_maindialogState = userState.CreateProperty<ChatState>(nameof(ChatState));

var _statemain = await _maindialogState.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, () => new ChatState());
_statemain.Email = "XXXXXX";
_statemain.DisplayName = "Ankit";
await _maindialogState.SetAsync(stepContext.Context, _statemain, cancellationToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are not actually saving the state in your code above, only setting the value. In nodejs the syntax would be

```js
await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context);
await this.userState.saveChanges(context);
```

I'm not sure what you have called the user or conversation state. You want to use that variable, not the state accessor (which appears to be _maindialogState) or your state variable (which appears to be _statemain).

Comment: This code is already there in my dialogbot.cs and I have checked state is getting saved in cosmos but still while retrieving, it is giving always null for next state.I am using my state variable to get the state.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are initiating the state storage? I'm assuming you have something like `const userState = new UserState(cosmosStorage)` or something similar. To be honest I'm not sure if there are reasons why this wouldn't work with Cosmos as compared to Blob, which is the implementation I use. What does the state object look like in CosmosDB?

Comment: Initiation of state-services.AddSingleton<IStorage>(new 
CosmosDbStorage(settings.CosmosDb));       services.AddSingleton<UserState>();
services.AddSingleton<ConversationState>();

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# but is there somewhere where you are connecting CosmosDbStorage to your state variables?